# Postgresql startup error : "Could not flush dirty data: Input/output error"

Tags: postgresql, crash, startup, ioerror

I am using Postgresql server v11.4 on RHEL 7. This is my load test environment and I have reach database size to 1TB.

Last night the server went down with errors “No Space left on Device” though there is about 2GB space available on FS about 1TB.

```
2020-03-03 17:11:37.202 IST pocdb schema1 109 2020-02-27 15:21:11 IST pid:27464 xid:0 ip:10.236.113.37 ERROR:  could not access status of transaction 0
2020-03-03 17:11:37.202 IST pocdb schema1 110 2020-02-27 15:21:11 IST pid:27464 xid:0 ip:10.236.113.37 DETAIL:  Could not write to file "pg_commit_ts/5198" at offset 90112: No space left on device.
2020-03-03 17:11:37.202 IST pocdb schema1 111 2020-02-27 15:21:11 IST pid:27464 xid:0 ip:10.236.113.37 STATEMENT:  UPDATE TEST SET STATUS = $1, LAST_UPDATE_DATE = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE ID = $2 AND STATUS = $4
2020-03-03 17:11:37.203 IST pocdb schema1 197 2020-02-27 15:23:51 IST pid:30398 xid:0 ip:10.236.113.36 **ERROR:  could not access status of transaction 0**
2020-03-03 17:11:37.203 IST pocdb schema1 198 2020-02-27 15:23:51 IST pi2020-03-03 17:14:29.937 IST   13 2020-02-27 15:15:14 IST pid:17705 xid:0 ip: **LOG:  database system is shut down**
```

I have tried to restart the postgres services many times but it is now failing with below message

```
2020-03-04 12:31:19.469 IST   1 2020-03-04 12:31:19 IST pid:21703 xid:0 ip: LOG:  database system shutdown was interrupted; last known up at 2020-03-04 11:49:08 IST
2020-03-04 12:31:19.704 IST   2 2020-03-04 12:31:19 IST pid:21703 xid:0 ip: LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2020-03-04 12:31:19.706 IST   3 2020-03-04 12:31:19 IST pid:21703 xid:0 ip: LOG:  redo starts at 136E/9E042C78
2020-03-04 12:32:07.312 IST   4 2020-03-04 12:31:19 IST pid:21703 xid:0 ip: LOG:  invalid record length at 1371/6CF69FD8: wanted 24, got 0
2020-03-04 12:32:07.312 IST   5 2020-03-04 12:31:19 IST pid:21703 xid:0 ip: LOG:  redo done at 1371/6CF69F88
2020-03-04 12:32:07.312 IST   6 2020-03-04 12:31:19 IST pid:21703 xid:0 ip: LOG:  last completed transaction was at log time 2020-03-03 17:13:36.683476+02
2020-03-04 12:32:07.319 IST   7 2020-03-04 12:31:19 IST pid:21703 xid:0 ip: LOG:  checkpoint starting: end-of-recovery immediate
2020-03-04 12:32:07.964 IST   8 2020-03-04 12:31:19 IST pid:21703 xid:0 ip: **PANIC:  could not flush dirty data: Input/output error**
2020-03-04 12:33:14.712 IST   7 2020-03-04 12:31:18 IST pid:21697 xid:0 ip: **LOG:  startup process (PID 21703) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted**
2020-03-04 12:33:14.712 IST   8 2020-03-04 12:31:18 IST pid:21697 xid:0 ip: LOG:  **aborting startup due to startup process failure**
2020-03-04 12:33:16.358 IST   9 2020-03-04 12:31:18 IST pid:21697 xid:0 ip: LOG:  **database system is shut down**
```

Can you please suggest way to startup the postgres server.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have I/O error in /var/log/messages ? You should first investigate and fix these if any.

Comment: yes checked and suspecting Disk corrupt error what is your though on it

Comment: Mar  4 16:03:21 illin2608 postmaster: 2020-03-04 16:03:21.840 IST   5 2020-03-04 16:03:21 IST pid:14409 xid:0 ip: LOG:  redirecting log output to logging collector process
Mar  4 16:03:21 illin2608 postmaster: 2020-03-04 16:03:21.840 IST   6 2020-03-04 16:03:21 IST pid:14409 xid:0 ip: HINT:  Future log output will appear in directory "/oravl02/postgres/log".
Mar  4 16:04:02 illin2608 kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev dm-10, sector 188876808

Comment: Mar  4 16:04:02 illin2608 kernel: EXT4-fs error (device dm-53): ext4_wait_block_bitmap:516: comm postmaster: Cannot read block bitmap - block_group = 12081, block_bitmap = 395837441
Mar  4 16:04:02 illin2608 kernel: EXT4-fs: 2 callbacks suppressed
Mar  4 16:04:02 illin2608 kernel: EXT4-fs (dm-53): Delayed block allocation failed for inode 11274721 at logical offset 96256 with max blocks 14 with error 5
Mar  4 16:04:02 illin2608 kernel: EXT4-fs (dm-53): This should not happen!! Data will be lost

Comment: Mar  4 16:04:02 illin2608 abrt-hook-ccpp: Process 14418 (postgres) of user 26 killed by SIGABRT - dumping core
Mar  4 16:04:11 illin2608 abrt-hook-ccpp: Write error: No space left on device
Mar  4 16:05:01 illin2608 kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev dm-10, sector 0
Mar  4 16:05:02 illin2608 kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev dm-10, sector 0
Mar  4 16:05:02 illin2608 kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev dm-10, sector 0
Mar  4 16:05:02 illin2608 kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev dm-10, sector 0

Comment: Mar  4 16:05:04 illin2608 abrt-hook-ccpp: Error writing '/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2020-03-04-16:04:02-14418.new/coredump'
Mar  4 16:05:07 illin2608 systemd: postgresql-11.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar  4 16:05:07 illin2608 systemd: Failed to start PostgreSQL 11 database server.
Mar  4 16:05:07 illin2608 systemd: Unit postgresql-11.service entered failed state.
Mar  4 16:05:07 illin2608 systemd: postgresql-11.service failed.

Comment: Please post output of: echo $PGDATA; df -h; lsblk

Comment: Anyhow this looks very bad: I understand that the ext4 file system hosting $PGDATA is broken. You should contact your system administrator or storage administrator to have a look possibly with smartctl tool. Maybe file system can be repaired with fsck but data loss is likely according to syslog. Be prepared to restore your database.

Comment: Thanks pifor.
My system admin team is executing  fsck on File System. 
Lets hope for best.